# why don't I see the query parameter when I hit enter in the search bar?

Tags: html, search

I was trying to implement a search bar in my web application:

```
<form method="get" action="NewServlet">
    <input type="search" />
</form>
```

When I type something in this search bar and hit enter, then the URL changes from

```
http://localhost:8084/App-1/tester.jsp
```

to

```
http://localhost:8084/App-1/NewServlet?
```

Why don't I see the search query parameter in the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to name your field:

```
<input type="search" name="query"/>
```

This will call:

```
http://localhost:8084/App-1/NewServlet?query=...
```